# Print hash keys sequentially in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have array of hashes and need to iterate and print the values in the sequence - `id,name,mailid`.

But when I print the content of keys, its keep shuffling. How do I print the conetent like below:

```
ID,NAME,EMAIL
vkk,Victor,vkk@test.com
smt,Smith,smt@test.com
```

Here is my script:

```
my @data = (
            { 
                'mail' => 'vkk@test.com',
                'name' => 'Victor',
                'id' => 'vkk'
            },
            { 
                'name' => 'Smith',
                'mail' => 'smt@test.com',
                'id' => 'smt'
            }
);

print "ID,NAME,EMAIL\n"; #header

for $content (@data){
    for $fields (keys %$content){
        print $content->{$fields}.",";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: `for $fields qw(id name mail)`? If you know the desired order of keys, then you can just specify it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo : Thanks, that works. But there is a problem printing the comma `,`.

Comment: I have added the condition in loop - `print "," if($fields ne 'mail');`

Comment: One way to solve this problem is to not use a hash. If you only have 3 fields, you might as well just use an array for the values.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo That should be `for $fields (qw(id name mail))`. A bug used to allow `for $fields qw(id name mail)`, but that was fixed ages ago.

Comment: They *are* being printed seqentially (in the order in which they are found in the hash.)

Comment: @ikegami Oops, thanks! I guess I was thinking of the suffix form with the implied variable. All the others seem to require parens. My bad.

Comment: Yes, the statement modifiers (`EXPR for LIST`) have no parens, but the flow control statements (`for (LIST) BLOCK`) do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation for [`keys()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys) says this:

> Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order.

So if you want to extract the data in a specific order, then you should specify that order.

```
for $content (@data){
    for $fields (qw(id name mail)) {
        print $content->{$fields}.",";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Or use a hash slice to simplify the code:

```
for $content (@data) {
  print join(',', @{$content}{qw(id name mail)}), "\n";
}
```

Comment: `@{$content}{qw(id name mail)}` can also be written as `$content->@{qw(id name mail)}`

Comment: ^--- Only after version 5.20. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax